# Qual a diferença entre "@id" e "@+id"?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Ao criar um componente, usamos `@+id/nome` para identificá-lo.

***Por exemplo:***

```
<TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_fornecedor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Fornecedor:"/>
```

Qual é a diferença de usar `@id/nome` *(sem o +)*, no lugar do `@+id/nome` ?
É correto usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`@+id/nome` serve para associar um nome ao componente, ele cria uma entrada na classe R.

`@id/nome` apenas identifica/referencia o componente, como por exemplo num RelativeLayout quando se quer indicar a posição de um componente em relação a outro.

`@id/nome` só pode ser utilizado após a utilização de `@+id/nome`.

Se você quiser pode utilizar apenas e sempre `@+id/nome`